# How are null-terminated strings terminated in C++11?

Tags: c++11, null-terminated, nullptr

Maybe it's stupid or obvious but I couldn't google any answer. What character ends a null-terminated string in `C++11`? `NULL` (which is in fact `0`) or new `nullptr`? On the one hand, `nullptr` is supposed to replace `NULL`. On the other, though, I'm not sure if `nullptr` is a character at all. Or can be interpreted as one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NULL` and `nullptr` has little to do with null-terminated strings. Both `NULL` and `nullptr` are used to denote a pointer which points to nothing, ie. *null*.

The null-termination of *c-style strings* is still (and has always) been denoted by a `CharT` having the integral value `0`; or as it's most often written when talking, through a *char-literal*; `'\0'`.

Remember that character types are nothing more than integral types with some special meaning.

Comparing a `char` to an `int` (which is the type of literal `0`) is allowed, it's also allowed to assign the value `0` to a `char`, as stated: a character type is an integral type.. and integral types hold integral values.

---

**Why this confusion?**

Back in the days when we didn't have `nullptr`, instead we had the macro `NULL` to denote that a certain pointer didn't have anything to point towards. The value of `NULL` is, and was, *implementation-specific* but the behaviour was well-defined; *it shall not compare equal to any pointer value that is actually pointing to something*.

As a result of how the behaviour of `NULL` was described plenty of compilers used `#define NULL 0`, or similar construct, resulting in a "feature" where one could easily compare `NULL` to any integral type (including `char`) to see if it's relation to the value zero.

---

With the previously stated in mind you'd often stumbled upon code such as the below, where the *for-condition* would be equivalent of having `*ptr != 0`.

```
char const * str = "hello world";

for (char const * ptr = str; *ptr != NULL; ++ptr) {
  ...    
}
```

<sup>**Lesson learned**: *Just because something works doesn't mean that it is correct...*</sup>

Comment: Is `myCharArray[24] = NULL;` incorrect then (since `NULL` isn't guaranteed to be `0`)?

Comment: @NPS `NULL` is guaranteed to be 0 in C++, however you still shouldn't do that. Just do `= { '\0' }` instead.

Comment: Filip wrote it's "implementation-specific". So which one is it?

Comment: @NPS it's just that.. implementation specific, the standard writes *" The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10). <sup>195</sup>"*, and the note says: *"Possible definitions **include** `0` and `0L`, but not `(void*)0`"*. (notice the "include", it's not guaranteed that implementations only use any of those two, and in either case: notes are normative)

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` and `nullptr` are completely separate concepts from the "null terminator". They have nothing more in common than the word "null". The null terminator is a character with value `0`. It has nothing to do with null pointers.

You can use `0` or `'\0'` etc.